# tcl extra characters after close-brace

Tags: awk, grep, character, tcl

i have this error Tcl error : extra characters after close-brace

```
proc exact {nick host handle channel text} {
global db_handle network;

set size exec curl -3 --ftp-ssl -k ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source/ | grep \\.r | awk '{print $5}'| awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }'

putnow "PRIVMSG #chnnel :source has $size"
}
```

Comment: That `set` line is not correct. I think you need to wrap the `exec` and command (in `[]`) to evaluate it and quote the command as a string (`{}`).

Comment: set size [exec curl -3 --ftp-ssl -k ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source/ {| grep \\.r | awk '{print $5}'| awk '{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }'}] so do you mean?

Comment: This is not your problem but your grep+awk set of pipelines should be reduced to just `awk '/\.r/{ SUM += $5} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }'`

Comment: now have this error: Tcl error [exact]: can't read "5": no such variable

Comment: To emphasize the point, single quotes have no special meaning in Tcl. Tcl's `{braces}` have the same functionality as the shell's `'single quotes'`

Answer (score 3):

Per the [exec(n) man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) you need to replace single quotes with curly braces. You also need `[]` around `exec` to invoke it:

```
    set size [exec curl -s -3 --ftp-ssl -k {ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source/} | grep \\.r | awk {{print $5}} | awk {{ SUM += $1} END { print SUM/1024/1024 }}]
```

That said, you don't need to invoke `grep` or `awk` at all. Everything you do with them here can be accomplished within the Tcl code:

```
proc exact {nick host handle channel text} {
    global db_handle network;

    set status 0
    set error [catch {
        set resp [exec curl -s -3 --ftp-ssl -k {ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source/}]
    } results options]
    if {$error} {
        set details [dict get $options -errorcode]
        if {[lindex $details 0] eq "CHILDSTATUS"} {
             set status [lindex $details 2]
             putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :curl error $status"
        }
    }
    set size 0
    foreach line [split $resp \n] {
        if {[string match {*\\.r*} $line]} {
            incr size [lindex $line 4]
        }
    }

    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :source has [expr {$size/1024/1024}]"
}
```

(I assume you've meant `$channel` rather than `#chnnel`.)

Comment: i have no output. in the partyline : Tcl error [exact]:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0

Comment: Does `curl -s -3 --ftp-ssl -k ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source` work on its own on the command line?

Comment: That's on the same machine as your bot? What about in `tclsh`? Run `tclsh` and paste `exec curl -s -3 --ftp-ssl -k ftp://xxx:xxx@192.210.0.8:2300/source`.

Comment: now is not in the network, and i use this wiht a eggdrop

Comment: I don't understand. Does the curl command work for you in bash on the same computer your eggdrop runs on? Could you run the tclsh command I've posted?

Comment: the tcl is loadet in a eggdrop, the curl ftp is not in the network

Comment: Are you saying that 192.210.0.8:2300 is **not** reachable from your eggdrop server?

Comment: Does your FTP password contain any special characters?

Comment: now : Tcl error [exact]: child process exited abnormally

Comment: Are you using the code from first or the second block?

Comment: I've updated the code again to report errors. Try it.

Comment: Try removing `-3` from `curl`'s options.

Comment: Well, your original question has been answered. It is difficult to debug networking code over StackOverflow comments and this comment section is getting unreasonably long. At this point I suggest that you ask for live assistance, e.g., in #eggdrop on Freenode or figure out how to debug it yourself with a `tclsh` session on your eggdrop server.